# How do I create a Rails migration that transfers all of the images from one table to another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations

I'm creating a migration that will do the following 3 things: create a table called `images`, transfer all of the images from the `products` table to the new `images` table, and then remove all of the image columns from the `products` table.

Everything works except the transferring images part. None of the image information transfers.

Here's the migration:

```
class CreateImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :images do |t|
      t.belongs_to :product
      t.string :image_file_name, :image_content_type
      t.integer :image_file_size
      t.boolean :main, :default => false

      t.timestamps
    end

    Product.all.each do |product|
      begin
        product.images.create(:image => product.image, :main => true)
      rescue => e
        logger.warn "Error while transferring images from product: #{product.name} to Images: #{e}"
      end
    end

    remove_column :products, :image_file_name
    remove_column :products, :image_content_type
    remove_column :products, :image_file_size
    remove_column :products, :image_updated_at

    add_index :images, [:product_id, :main]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not execute filesystem operations like file processing within an ActiveRecord migration. This is mainly because ActiveRecord migrations are executed within a database transaction and if the transaction files, changes to the files will not be rolled buck. Plus, if you are trying to process large amount of files, you may face unexpected connection timeouts to the database or similar errors.

You must create a Rake task inside your lib directory and run it after the migration has finished. Such rake task should first copy the files to a new directory and then delete the old files. You may find this post helpful: http://fernandomarcelo.com/2012/05/paperclip-how-to-move-existing-attachments-to-a-new-path/. It is not paperclip specific.

Finally, run the remove_column statements in a different migration.

```
class CreateImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :images do |t|
      t.belongs_to :product
      t.string :image_file_name, :image_content_type
      t.integer :image_file_size
      t.boolean :main, :default => false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Run your task manually here.

Finally, execute the following migration.

```
class RemoveImagesFromProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
    remove_column :products, :image_file_name
    remove_column :products, :image_content_type
    remove_column :products, :image_file_size
    remove_column :products, :image_updated_at

    add_index :images, [:product_id, :main]
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful tip. Do you know how I should transfer the images though?